# std::array aggregate initialization and template integral types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, aggregate-initialization

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of `std::array`, we find that it can be initialized as it follows (using aggregate initialization):

```
struct S {
    S(): arr{0,1} { }
    std::array<int,2> arr;
};
```

Anyway, a problem arises in this case:

```
template<int N>
struct S {
    S(): arr{/*??*/} { }
    std::array<int,N> arr;
};
```

How can one initialize the array while constructing `s` (as an example with values from `0` to `N-1` or using a `constexpr`ed function to which to pass the indexes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behold the massively under-utilized power of [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
template <int N>
struct S {
    S() {
        std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
    }

    std::array<int, N> arr;
};
```

Though if you really want to use aggregate initialization, there's always [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (requires C++14 but there's lots of C++11 solutions on SO):

```
template <int N>
struct S {
    S() : S(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{}) {}

    std::array<int, N> arr;
private:
    template <int... Is>
    S(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> )
        : arr{Is...}
    { }
};
```

Comment: @LorahAttkins Correct. And making it private so nobody else can pass in an invalid sequence.

Comment: What about `std::iota` when used with a `std::array` of `std::vector`? Doesn't it mean initializing twice the vectors?

Comment: @skypjack You can't use `std::iota` with an array of vectors because a vector isn't incrementable.

Comment: Ahahah... You are right, sorry. Summertime does not forgive!! :-D